# lisp: the variable MARKEDIT is unbound

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

This is probably a simple fix, but I'm trying to walk through the MarkEdit example in the Ceramic [tutorial](http://ceramic.github.io/docs/tutorial.html), and I'm having trouble getting the files to build.

I'm not sure what context I need to be in or to create -- I've tried running the instructions they provide:

```
(ql:quickload :ceramic)

(ceramic.bundler:bundle :markedit)
```

and I get the error in my title line. I've also tried cloning the MarkEdit [repo](https://github.com/ceramic/markedit/) (which has slightly different instructions, but gives me the same result) and loading `markedit.asd` before running these `quickload` and `ceramic.bundler` calls, but I get the same error.

What's the correct way to build the context that I need in order to run the bundler?

Comment: could this be the case: https://github.com/ceramic/markedit/issues/2 ?

Comment: I have tried to quickload markedit and get an error: `System "markedit" not found.` This error still occurs even if I try to run the quick load from the directory that I have cloned Markedit into, i.e. the directory that has `markedit.asd` in it that describes the system.

Comment: have you cloned markedit in a folder where quicklisp can find it? try cloning/copying it in `~/quicklisp/local-projects` and it should be found by quicklisp

Comment: That did it, thanks.